# XNA - Freezing Menu Error

Tags: c#, xna

When I click the down arrow it gets stuck on the second selection and up or down no longer work, how would I fix that?

Second Question: How to prevent freezing when changing menu items? When I change menu items, it freezes of the second selection. Here is the code concerning this question;

```
keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
mouse = Mouse.GetState();

    if (keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    {
        if (selected > 0) selected--;
        else selected.Equals(buttonList.Count - 1);
    }

    if (keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    {
        if (selected < buttonList.Count - 1) selected++;
        else selected.Equals(0);
    }

    prevMouse = mouse;
    prevKeyboard = keyboard;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code you had, after being modified worked fine for me. Here it is with modifications:

```
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Up))
        {
            if (selected > 0) selected--;
            else{selected = buttonList.Count - 1;}
        }

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Down))
        {
            if (selected < buttonList.Count - 1) selected++;
            else {selected = 0;}
        }

        prevMouse = mouse;
        prevKeyboard = keyboard;
    }

    public bool CheckMouse()
    {
        return (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released);
    }

    public bool CheckKeyboard(Keys key)
    {
        //Here is the only thing that needed to be changed, based on your original post
        //you were checking if both keys were down originally, meaning it was always 
        // true while a button was pressed. if the previous keyboard was down,
        //and the current keyboard is up, it means the button was released.
        return (keyboard.IsKeyUp(key) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements don't make very much sense, and they're both exactly the same:

```
if (keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
```

but if they were intended to be the same, one would think that you'd just just combine them into one.

It appears like you're trying to use the following paradigm

```
if (keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Down) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))

...

if (keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
```

---

another oddity I notice is the way you're using the `Equals()` method.

You're not doing anything with it's return value.

`Equals()` is used for comparison and it returns a bool telling you whether the elements are equal, but It looks like you're using it for assignment or something.

are you looking for something like

```
else 
    selected = 0;
```

instead of

```
else selected.Equals(0);
```